# routing in javascript or php function

Tags: php, javascript

I was wondering if there is a way of doing this:

let's say I'm calling this method:

`object.segment1_segment2_segment3();`

```
// or 
$object->segment1_segment2_segment3();
```

What you have to know is that segment1_segment2_segment3() is not necessarily an existing method, and I want my program to guess which existing function to call, based on the segments in the object's method.

I don't know if i'm clear enough but, I would like to know if you think it's possible, and what would be the cleanest way to do such a MAGIC thing ^^

good day to you mister reader ^^

Comment: Can I ask why you can't use them as arguments like `object.some_funct(segment1, segment2, segment3)`?

Comment: the functions I'm about to build, will do instructions dynamically.
let's say the segments could have 4 possible choices each. I'm not going to write 4*4*4 functions :D alright that doesn't answer your question, I want to build some sort of human friendly functions, instead of relaying on arguments passed to the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in PHP you could override the `__call($method, $args)` method. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods

in JavaScript you have `__noSuchMethod__`, but it's not a standard. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod

Answer (score 1):

not sure of javascript but you could use php's `__call()` magic method to do the magic, here is the tutorial by net.tutsplus.com have a read it's worth it.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/deciphering-magic-methods-in-php/